# Fixed Toggle Menu in One Page Website Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, menuitem

How can I stop the menu items from sliding in front of the menu bar?
Menu items shouldn't be sliding in front of the menu bar, should simply drop down, or slide on the back...
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/415x8e5w/3/)

JS

```
//------This slides menu contet down ------:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu-button").click(function(){
    $("#menu-items").slideToggle("slow");
  });

//----This brings menu content back up when an item is clicked -----:

$('#menu-items li a').on("click", function(){
        $('#menu-items').slideUp();
    });

});

//----this adds smooth scrolling and negative space for Header compensation ----:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.link').each(function (event) {
            if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 75) {
                $('.link').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    });
});


$(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top -75)
                }, 850);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;        
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section { width: 100%; height: 100%; color: white;}
#section01, #section03, #section05 { background: #24354c; } 
#section02, #section04, #section06 { background: #374962; } 


#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #152233;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#menu-items {
    display:none;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

#menu-items li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #297d35;
    background-color: #67af32;
}

#menu-items li:hover {
    background: #4a9529;
}

#menu-items li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-button {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 18px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">

<img id="menu-button" src="http://downtownkitchenmke.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/menuButton.png" alt="menu" border="0" width="340" height="40" />

<ul id="menu-items">
    <li><a href="#section01">SECTION 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section02">SECTION 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section03">SECTION 03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section04">SECTION 04</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section05">SECTION 05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section06">SECTION 06</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<section id="section01"><h1>SECTION 01</h1></section>
<section id="section02"><h1>SECTION 02</h1></section>
<section id="section03"><h1>SECTION 03</h1></section>
<section id="section04"><h1>SECTION 04</h1></section>
<section id="section05"><h1>SECTION 05</h1></section>
<section id="section06"><h1>SECTION 06</h1></section>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you need?

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add another div before the dropdown instead of trying to use Padding-top on the menu-items list:

Add div 'header-buffer':

```
<div id='header-buffer'></div>    
<ul id="menu-items">
   <li><a href="#section01">SECTION 01</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section02">SECTION 02</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section03">SECTION 03</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section04">SECTION 04</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section05">SECTION 05</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section06">SECTION 06</a></li>
</ul>
```

Remove the padding from "menu-items" and add height for "header-buffer":

```
#menu-items {
 display:none;
 list-style: none;
 width: 100%;
}

#header-buffer {   
 width: 100%;
 height:75px
}
```

Comment: It Works! Here's the **[Fixed Version](http://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/415x8e5w/6/)** Thanks a lot!